# SetWindowPos() owner z-order

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to understand the purpose of the `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER` flag when calling the [`SetWindowPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

The documentation seems to only mention the change of the owner's z-order in one place:

> If a topmost window is repositioned to the bottom (**HWND_BOTTOM**) of the Z order or after any non-topmost window, it is no longer topmost. When a topmost window is made non-topmost, its owners and its owned windows are also made non-topmost windows.

Does this mean that in all other cases the z-order of the owner window is unchanged?

For example, if I specify `NO_ZORDER` does it automatically mean that the owner's z-order will not change?

What is the purpose of this flag? Only to prevent pushing the owner window towards the bottom through `SetWindowPos(ownedWindow, ...)`?

Comment: Don't try to second-guess the API or over-complicate things. Follow the documentation as written. If you don't want to change owner window's position in the Z order, then pass `SWP_NOOWNERZORDER`. Simple. If that means you pass the flag 90% of the times you call the function, fine. So do I.

Comment: It has no effect on child windows, fwiw, it only affects owned popups.

Comment: @CodyGray okay... but what does SetWindowPos do the owner's Z-order when you *don't* pass the flag? The documentation doesn't say!

Comment: "If a topmost window is repositioned to the bottom (HWND_BOTTOM) of the Z order or after any non-topmost window, it is no longer topmost. When a topmost window is made non-topmost, **its owners and its owned windows are also made non-topmost windows.**" - SWP_NOOWNERZORDER prevents that for owners.